# Creating "Rooms" for a game in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I working on a text-based adventure game in objective-c and I've got a lot of the parts completed including the input/output system, and command parser. The only thing I can't figure out is the best way to create the "rooms".

At first I tried using XML to store them and then using NSXMLParser to read them but that didn't allow for enough complexity.

So now I've decided to create a class "AbstractLocation" and create a subclass for each room.
But, I'm having trouble connecting everything. These are my classes:

Controller
     Controls the input/output and core parts of the game
AbstractLocation
     A generic room for the game that can be subclassed to create each specific room
CreateMap
     Creates each specific room from the AbstractLocation class
Location_room1
Location_room2
ect...

I'm wondering how to access the instance of Controller class that was created in Interface Builder from each Location_roomx, because each room is created programmatically in the CreateMap class so I can't use an IBOutlet.

If am also open to suggestions for a better way to create the rooms system for the game.

Comment: Creating a subclass for each room seems... bad.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a better way to create the rooms?

Comment: @Sarathi: Yes. Create a Room object with properties like `CGSize dimensions`, `NSArray objects`, `NSString description`, etc.. and then at startup read in a propety list with an array of dictionary objects, each one with all of the information necessary to construct a Room object. And then it's just a matter of pulling up the appropriate Room object when the player moves into it.

Comment: @darvids0n: I thought of doing something similar to that, but each room has it's own set of actions that can be performed, and they may modify a variable output a string to the player, or add an item to the inventory. I used the subclasses so I can override a function that performs these actions for each room. I haven't figured out a way to do this if each room were an object.

Comment: Create a `[Room serialize]` method which converts the action or message that a specific `Room` instance would present to a string. You can use your own string-based serialization format e.g "`m:Message`" to display the message `Message` to the player, "`a:set:hp,-2`" to take 2 health points off the player (an avalanche or something occurs), or "`a:give:34`" to give the player an item with itemID=34 (you can look up the item's associated characteristics in a table of possible items). Then you can add that to the `Room`'s dictionary as, say, an `NSString *action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need IBOutlet.

Just define a property on AbstractLocation, and in the code that creates the rooms, assign a pointer to the Controller to it.

The point of IBOutlet is to let Interface Builder do the same kind of thing, but without code. When you are writing the code, you don't need IBOutlet, you just need a property, and code to assign a value to it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Another problem was that I was creating the rooms in the init method of CreateMap and so the controller property was null, I changed it to the awakeFromNib method and it worked.

Comment: @SarathiJ.Hansen , Have you create room in objective c, can you please help me how to create room , or any sample, i am trying to do it, but dont know how to start and where to start. Please help me